# Staged 'saves' with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

One thing I love with Meteor is that updates, inserts, and removes done on the client side are persisted, automatically, on the server-side. Most of the time this is great. But sometimes you want to use Meteor's collections for display logic, or you want to have specific, staged 'saves' that the user has to specifically commit to. And so you want to continue to use collections for rendering, but you don't necessarily want those changes *saved* to the database.

Perhaps an example will help make this clear.

I have a form that renders a specified map origin.

```
<template name='map'>
 <button class='select-origin'>Select Origin</button>
 {{#with currentMap}}
   {{this.latitude}} - {{this.longitude}}
 {{/with}}
</template>

Template.map.helpers({
 currentMap: function(){ return Maps.findOne(Session.get('currentMap')) };
});
```

And when I'm editing a map, latitude and longitude will be read from the database and rendered appropriately.

But I also want to let the user select a new map origin and *update the template without saving the new map origin*. I want the user to click on the map, which I can then use to update the collection *client-side*, which will then update the template. But I want the user to specifically click `save` and *then* have the new latitude and longitude persisted on the server. Something like this is easy in Backbone (in which `set` and `save` are distinct), but it doesn't seem easy in Meteor.

Does anyone have good strategies to deal with these situations?

Comment: Im a bit confused, if you want the user to update the map position without saving it can't it be done by directly telling the map to move to a different position? When they press save then just update it on the server?

Comment: There are times that I can do this, but in the example I show I want the template to update with the newly selected map position. And I want to use this template _without_ having to save the new position to the database. I want to temporarily _set_ the attributes, instead of _saving_ the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

for this kind of issues I use the `Session` object

you already keep your current map in the Session. You could apply all the changes to the object in the Session and once the user clicks save, update the MiniMongo instance and let Meteor update the server.

I am not sure what attributes the `CurrentMap` object contains, as the set operation is not shown in your code, but it seems you could replace

```
Template.map.helpers({
 currentMap: function(){ return Maps.findOne(Session.get('currentMap')) };
});
```

with

```
Template.map.helpers({
 currentMap: function(){ return Session.get('currentMap') };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I didn't know objects could (or should?) be stored in `Session`. I'll give this a try.